# Android separate layouts for 480x320 or less and others

Tags: android, android-layout

I want separate layouts. I tried to create folders as in [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but no success. I create `layout` for 480x320 or less and `layout-normal` for others so my folder struct looks like

```
-res
-- layout
-- layout-normal
```

but in test 480x320 still take layout from `layout-normal`.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Try ldi, mdi, hdpi, etc

Comment: 480x320 is typically layout-land (or layout-mdpi-land), while 320x480 is typically layout (or layout-mdpi or layout-port or layout-mdpi-port)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this link on how to deal with multiple screen sizes.  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

However, the short answer is that you can simply create a folder called 
   res/layout-sw320dp

which would house layouts for any device whose smallest width is 320.  May not be exactly 320, but you get the idea.